# Why my label doesn´t show the text array?

Tags: swift, save, option-type, fatal-error

I´m new at programming and I get an error that I wasn´t able to solve yet, even the question didn´t help me: What does “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value” mean?

Here is the error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-10-27 18:30:48.283483+0200 Inspireme1.0[1149:631849] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Here is my code:

```
var quotes: RandomItems! = RandomItems([

"Jonas",
"Mary",
"Michael",
"Jeff",                 
"Sarah",

])

@IBAction func PresentText(_ sender: Any) {

PresentingLabel.text = quotes.next() //<-- Error

}

var randomItems: RandomItems?


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
// Code to load the struct again after the view appears.
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
quotes = defaults.codable(RandomItems.self, forKey: "quotes")
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
// Code to save struct before the view disappears.
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if let quotes = quotes {
    defaults.set(codable: quotes, forKey: "quotes")
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't repost your questions. If needed, edit your previous question.

Comment: @DávidPásztor no it´s not a duplicate. I´ve already said that I didn´t found a solution there. I wrote this in my question.

Comment: You've posted the same code with the same error message as the question you posted an hour ago. How is it not the same?